# Android Split Install Error(-2): Module_Unavailable Error

Tags: java, android, google-play, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature

I am trying to implement on demand delivery feature in my android app. Now I am working on examples to understand how it works but when I try to install a dynamic module it shows an error message "Split Install Error(-2): A requested module is not available (to this user/device, for the installed apk). (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/splitinstall/model/SplitInstallErrorCode.html#MODULE_UNAVAILABLE)"

I have seen many examples and also followed google's split install documentation, and I have also seen many StackOverflow Question/Answers but I can't find any solution.

**My code**

**MainActivity.java(Base App):**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallManager;
import com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallManagerFactory;
import com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallRequest;
import com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallSessionState;
import com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener;
import com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.model.SplitInstallSessionStatus;
import com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import java.io.File;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button download;



private int mySessionId;

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private SplitInstallManager splitInstallManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    download = findViewById(R.id.download);



    splitInstallManager = SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(getApplicationContext());

    download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            downloadDynamicModule();
        }
    });






}

private void downloadDynamicModule() {


    SplitInstallRequest request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder().addModule("dynamic").build();

    SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener listener = new SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateUpdate(SplitInstallSessionState splitInstallSessionState) {
            if(splitInstallSessionState.sessionId() == mySessionId) {
                switch (splitInstallSessionState.status()) {
                    case SplitInstallSessionStatus.DOWNLOADING:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dynamic Module downloading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Update progress bar.
                        break;
                    case SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Dynamic Module downloaded");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dynamic Module downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Session Not Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    splitInstallManager.registerListener(listener);

    splitInstallManager.startInstall(request).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to Install "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "ExceptionV: " + e);
                }
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Integer sessionId) {
                    mySessionId = sessionId;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success"+sessionId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest(Base App):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.package.dynamicfeaturemoduleexample">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DynamicFeatureModuleExample"
    android:name="com.google.android.play.core.splitcompat.SplitCompatApplication">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

**Gradle(Base App):**

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 29

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.package.dynamicfeaturemoduleexample"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 19
    versionName '2.9'

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}



buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


bundle {
    density {
        // Different APKs are generated for devices with different screen densities; true by default.
        enableSplit true
    }
    abi {
        // Different APKs are generated for devices with different CPU architectures; true by default.
        enableSplit true
    }
    language {
        // This is disabled so that the App Bundle does NOT split the APK for each language.
        // We're gonna use the same APK for all languages.
        enableSplit false
    }
}
dynamicFeatures = [':dynamic', ':dynamicfeature', ':newfeature']
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

**DynamicActivity.java(Dynamic Feature):**

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;


public class DynamicActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dynamic_module);
}


}
```

**AndoridManifest(Dynamic Feature):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
package="com.package.dynamic"
split="dynamic">

<dist:module
    dist:instant="false"
    dist:title="@string/title_dynamic">
    <dist:delivery>
        <dist:on-demand />
    </dist:delivery>
    <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
</dist:module>

<application>
    <activity
        android:name="com.package.dynamic.DynamicActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_dynamic">
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**Gradle(Dynamic Feature):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.package.dynamic"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 16
    versionName '2.6'

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules-dynamic-features.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation project(":app")
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1@aar'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
}
```

[image: My Google Play Developer Console App Bundle Reference]

I have Edited the run configuration to "Apk from app bundle" and I am testing the app via Internal Testing Track but it is not working.

Comment: Found a solution?

Comment: @MerthanE it is possible the name you're passing to the download function or nav graph is incorrect. Especial ly if module name and title are not the same. Use the name that is displayed in module.gradle e.g., if app name is Canteen App and gradle shows the modules as Canteen_App.authmodule, the name to pass is authModule

Comment: @AdhiamboOyier Unfortunately not the case for me, names are the same :/

Comment: @MerthanE including case? If so, let's try something else

Comment: Yep it's just called "dynamic" in my case, I'm not sure if it's maybe related to Google not yet having reviewed my app so I might wait for that to be finished to be sure. @AdhiamboOyier

Comment: @MerthanE app not reviewd is not really a problem. You can upload a bundle to internal test track and you will be able to download it instantly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231430/discussion-between-adhiambo-oyier-and-merthan-e).

Comment: Is your code available in a public repo?

Comment: Hello is it resolved? am also having same issue with install time delivery... the feat module and title have same name but getting either split api not available/module not available... these errors are keep switching

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Run > Edit configurations` and select `Default APK`, or make sure all your modules are checked as in the picture.

[image]